# Create a program that asks users for input (integer) and outputs the input(integer) squared

Tags: python

Create a program that asks users for input (integer) and outputs the input(integer) squared.

Title pretty much says it all. 
Help me please!

Comment: `print(int(input("Enter a number: ")) ** 2)`

Comment: You should provide some details regarding what you have tried before seeking an answer. Requests such as "write me a program to do x" are not appropriate on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and Powers Math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043913/python-and-powers-math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
interger = input("Please enter an interger: ")
print(int(interger)**2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Fairly Simple:

```
x = int(input())
print(x*x)
```