# solution to power of the numbers in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

My assignment in python programming ask me to arrive at the solution of a program where we can find the power numbers.

For eg.
2^4 = 16
Is it possible to get this solution directly without using the actual logic in programming?

Comment: ```2**4```. What about ```**```. And what is *actual logic in programming?*

Comment: This thing should be marked as duplicate anyway just look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043913/python-and-powers-math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ** directly. (i.e) 2 ** 4. In python x^y is written as x ** y. Hope it will be helpful for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have got a well understanding of your question.
I'm going to assume that you are asking how to get for instance 2 to the power of 4 (i.e. **2^4**).

In python, the power operator is actually predifined as `**`. So `2^4` is written `2 ** 4`.

I expect I have answered your question.

**In addition ...**
The `**` operator is more CPU consuming so if you want for instance to rise a number to the power of 2, prefer using `number * number` instead of `number ** 2`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, an exponent operator is `**`.

When you write `2**4`, it means `2^4` in mathematical language.